# Are rings $\mathbb Q[i]$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}i]$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I wonder if the rings $\mathbb Q[i]=\{a+bi: a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}i]=\{a+\sqrt{3}bi:a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ are isomorphic.

I tried map $f(a+bi)=a+\sqrt3bi$ but then it doesn't satisfy cond. $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$

Comment: Is there an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$ that squares to -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbb{Q}[i] \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i]$ then $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ contains a square root of $-3$, i.e. $\sqrt{3}i$ or $-\sqrt{3}i$. But then already $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[i]$. Similarly $\mathbb{Q}[i] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i]$, so $\mathbb{Q}[i] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i]$, which is false.

Comment: Is it a misunderstanding of mine, or is it a typo: "contains a square root of −3i", not just a square root of -3?

Comment: why if they are isomorphic then $Q[i]$ contains -3 ?

Comment: @GyroGearloose: It was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @Jessy: If there exists an isomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i] \to \mathbb{Q}[i]$ then, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is the underlying prime field, we have $\phi(q) = q$ for exery $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. We therefore have $\phi(\sqrt{3}i)^2 = \phi((\sqrt{3}i)^2) = \phi(-3) = -3$. So $z = \phi(\sqrt{3}i)$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$, and therefore in particular of $\mathbb{C}$, with $z^2 = -3$. This means that $z = \pm \sqrt{3} i$. Thus $\sqrt{3}i \in \mathbb{Q}[i]$. Because $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{3}i$ it already contains $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}i]$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\Bbb Q[i]$ contained a square root of $-3$. This would mean:

$(a + bi)^2 = -3$, for some $a,b \in \Bbb Q$.

Expanding on the left, we have:

$a^2 - b^2 + i(2ab) = -3 = -3 + 0i$

Equating real and imaginary parts, we first find that $ab = 0$, and since $\Bbb Q$ is an integral domain, either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ (cannot be both, since then $a^2 - b^2 = 0 \neq -3)$.

Since $a^2 > 0$ for any $a \neq 0$ in $\Bbb Q$, we cannot have $b = 0$, therefore, the only possibility is:

$-b^2 = -3 \implies b^2 = 3$.

But this would mean $b = \pm \sqrt{3} \in \Bbb Q$, contradiction.

Now if there *were* an isomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Q[\sqrt{-3}] \to \Bbb Q[i]$,

we would have for $a + bi = \phi(\sqrt{-3})$, that:

$(a+bi)^2 = [\phi(\sqrt{-3})]^2 = \phi((\sqrt{-3})^2) = \phi(-3) = -3$, and this is impossible.